# Parsing a log file with sed

Tags: unix, sed

I'm trying to parse this line:

> 2017-09-18T11:00:03,059 INFO  [01272636] :sasdemo - New client connection (198880) accepted from server port 8561 for trusted SAS
>   peer user sasdemo.

into something like this:

> 2017-09-18T11:00:03,sasdemo,LOGIN,SUCCESS,Successful Login

I'm quite new to the use of sed, but if I'm not wrong, I need to store in the search all the chars untill the first comma `[^,]*` and use it in the replace like `\1` but how can I retrieve the user `sasdemo`?

Comment: where do you extract "LOGIN,SUCCESS,Successful Login" from?

Comment: they are simple text in the replace part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following does what you want:

```
sed -n '/New client connection ([0-9]*) accepted/{
            s/,.* peer user \(.*\)\./,\1,LOGIN,SUCCESS,Successful Login/;p
       }'
```

- `-n` means "don't print each line", the command `p` is used to print only the selected lines
- The command starts with an "address", i.e. the code block in brackets will only be run if the input line contains "New client connection" etc.
- Grouping (backslashed parentheses) is used to extract the username, `\1` refers to the first such a group

Comment: Thanks for the answer, what if my string would be something more long, like this: 2017-09-18T11:00:03,059 INFO  [01272636] :sasdemo - New client connection (198880) accepted from server port 8561 for trusted SAS peer user sasdemo.  Encryption level is Credentials using encryption algorithm SASPROPRIETARY. Peer IP address and port are [::ffff:191.0.0.7]:55438 for APPNAME=SAS.

Comment: Is there something smarted than this?: sed -n '/New client connection ([0-9]*) accepted/{s/,.* peer user \(.*\)\ .* .* .* .* .* .* .* .* .* .* .* .* .* .* .* .* .*/,\1,LOGIN,SUCCESS,Successful Login/;p}'

Comment: `.*.*` is the same as `.*`, so there should be something simpler, yeah.

Comment: But i get a different output with this: sed -n '/New client connection ([0-9]*) accepted/{s/,.* peer user \(.*\)\ .*/,\1,LOGIN,SUCCESS,Successful Login/;p}'

Comment: `\.` means literal dot. Why do you have `\.*` at the end of the pattern?

Answer (score 1):

With **awk**:

```
awk -F',|[[:space:]]*|\\.' '/New c.* accepted/{ 
        print $1,$(NF-1),"LOGIN,SUCCESS,Successful Login" 
    }' OFS=',' logfile
```

The output (for one line):

```
2017-09-18T11:00:03,sasdemo,LOGIN,SUCCESS,Successful Login
```

Comment: What could be the benefit of using awk instead of sed?

Comment: @GoingSolo, it will give you an additional benefit and flexibility in case if you need to extract additional fields(or deal with a few needed fields) from the line, rearrange the fields, make arithmetic operations or text processing operations

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the man page for sed?  It will give you all of the command options.

You can use the `\1 \2 \3` options in sed to parse multiple strings with the
`\(` and `\)` to identify the strings:  `\(sasdemo\)` and use `.` between each string you're looking for.